# Take a file of regexes and return the first match for each in another file

Tags: bash, regex, grep, awk

I have two files. `a.txt` has a list of regexes, separated by newlines. `b.txt` has lines, some of which match the regexes in `a.txt`.

What I want: A command (grep, probably) that will take the two files, and for each line in `a.txt` prints the first whole-line match from `b.txt`.
An ideal solution would also print the regex itself as a prefix and, if there is no match, print 'no match' or something else distinctive. One missing either or both of these is, however, good enough.

What I'm currently using to test solutions:

a.txt:

```
[abc]*qs
ab[cqs]*
w+x+
```

b.txt:

```
aqs
abqs
abs
```

Best things I've tried are `grep -xf a.txt b.txt`, which prints

```
aqs
abqs
abs
```

and `grep -xcf a.txt b.txt` which prints `3`.

Ideal output would be

```
[abc]*qs aqs
ab[cqs]* abqs
w+x+ None
```

Minimally acceptable output would be

```
aqs
abqs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while read -r pattern; do
   printf '%s ' "$pattern"
   grep -x -m 1 "$pattern" b.txt || printf '%s\n' 'None'
done <a.txt
```

It works by reading patterns one by one, running `grep` for each of them and printing (`printf`) additional information where needed.

Note: `grep -m 1` stops after the first match found, it's not POSIX though. If you don't have this option, replace the line containing `grep` with this one:

```
{ grep -x "$pattern" b.txt || printf '%s\n' 'None'; } | head -n 1
```